# How can i create a multivariable function in matlab out of matrix data?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, matrix

but i want to make a program in which i can generate a function of multiple variables that depend on the number of rows of a matrix.

```
for k = 1:sizel;

f(k)=(alpha(k,1)+(beta(k,1)*p(k))+(gamma(k,1)*p(k)^2));

end

cost=(sum(f))
```

this is for the purpose of optimization so i need that at the end the variables are declares as `p(1),p(2),p(3)`... these will be the input for my function.

Note: i dont want to assign values to the variables because this will be done be the optimization algorithm in the optimization toolbox.

here is the complete code

```
function  cost = cost(p) ;
clc 
clear

costfunctionconstantsmatrix;
sizel=size(CostFormulaconstants);

alpha=CostFormulaconstants(:,1);

beta=CostFormulaconstants(:,2);

gamma=CostFormulaconstants(:,3);



for k = 1:sizel;

f(k)=(alpha(k,1)+(beta(k,1)*p(k))+(gamma(k,1)*p(k)^2));

end

cost=(sum(f))


end
```

i used the symbolic approach and i got the correct answer for the cost indeed, i got something like this: (53*p(1))/10 + (11*p(2))/2 + (29*p(3))/5 + p(1)^2/250 + (3*p(2)^2)/500 + (9*p(3)^2)/1000 + 1100. But when i try to specify my function to be optimized in the optimization toolbox it tells me that the variables p are sym and cannot be converted to double. the trouble is how to convert this expression to double so that the optimization algorithm can input values for the variable p(1), p(2) and p(3)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly
The input to the function is the matrix and the vector p ? if so then the submitted answer would work
you could also check symbolic variables 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html

Comment: i used the symbolic approach and i got the correct answer for the cost indeed, i got something like this: (53*p(1))/10 + (11*p(2))/2 + (29*p(3))/5 + p(1)^2/250 + (3*p(2)^2)/500 + (9*p(3)^2)/1000 + 1100. But when i try to specify my function to be optimized in the optimization toolbox it tells me that the variables p are sym and cannot be converted to double. the trouble is how to convert this expression to double so that the optimization algorithm can input values for the variable p(1), p(2) and p(3).

Comment: Have you checked out this http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the matrix as an argument to the function?

```
function cost = fcn(my_mat)

[m,n] = size(my_mat);
f = zeros(m,1);
for k = 1:m % for example
   f(k)=(alpha(k,1)+(beta(k,1)*p(k))+(gamma(k,1)*p(k)^2));
end
cost = sum(f);

end
```

Comment: This will give an error since the vector p isn't defined and i think he said p is to be passed to the function so might want to edit that

Comment: @mhmsa Yes, I have assumed that all necessary variables are either defined in the function, passed as additional parameters or are global variables. The code is just meant to illustrate the process rather than work off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not entirely clear to me but I believe you wish to generate a series of functions in which the variables `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma` are constants with different values for each function, and the vector `p` is an argument.

What confuses me in your question is that you use the index `k` for both the constants and the arguments, which I think is not what you intended to write. Assuming I understand your goal, a solution may make use of function handles.

The notation `f(k) = @(p) p(1)+p(2)` for example, generates a function that adds `p(1)` and `p(2)`. Abbreviating `CostFormulaconstants` to `cf`, the following would generate a series of functions, one for each row in `cf`.

```
for k = 1 : size(cf, 1)
    f{k} = @(p) cf(k,1) + cf(k,2)*p(1) + cf(k,3)*p(2)^2;
end
```

You can supply individual function handles to callers from the optimization toolbox simply with `f{3}` for the third function, for example. A call to `f{3}` would look like

```
a = f{3}([3,4]);
```

If your functions are indeed all polynomials, `polyval` may be worth a look as well.

**EDIT**: After clarification, the problem seems a bit simpler, no need for function handles. Why not simply

```
function c = cost(p)
c = 0;
cf = [...]; % your coefficients here.
for k = 1 : size(cf, 1)
    c = c + cf(k,1) + cf(k,2)*p(k) + cf(k,3)*p(k)^2;
end
```

Comment: for example what i want to get is:

f1=(0.004*(p(1)^2))+(5.3*p(1))+500
f2=(0.006*(p(2)^2))+(5.5*p(2))+400
f3=(0.009*(p(3)^2))+(5.8*p(3))+200

and then cost=f1+f2+f3

after this i´ll proceed to minimize-cost